# Twilio, how do I get the voice response from phone

Tags: python, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm currently trying to integrate dialogflow with twilio. I want to be able to parse the voice response that my customer gives to the bot. How do I get the voice response; and send response back based on certain voice texts.

As of now; when someone calls the phone it replies Hello; then I want to be able to grab what customer replies; then respond it back appropriately. So far I am using the webhook "A call comes in". 
 Would this require extra library that translates voice to text? Or does twilio offer it.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from flask import Flask
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse

app = Flask(__name__)
# using os.environ['account_sid']

@app.route('/voice', methods=["GET","POST"])
def voice():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.say("hello")
    return str(resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the voice gather command. Twilio does offer speech recognition itself with this command.

```
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Gather, VoiceResponse, Say

response = VoiceResponse()
gather = Gather(input='speech dtmf', timeout=3, num_digits=1)
gather.say('Hello!')
response.append(gather)

print(response)
```

Documentation here -> https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather